# AuthFailed at /social-auth/complete/linkedin-oauth2/

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api, django-socialauth

I am a bit confuse while LinkedIn `r_basicprofile` is not authorized for my application after completing the necessary process.

I have check some related question on **SO** but it appears that solutions are not working for me maybe because of the different changes on  LinkedIn social oauth.

`Authentication failed: Scope 'r_basicprofile' is not authorized for your application`

My backend settings, frontend and  API are correct, but I don't know why it is not working.

```
'social_core.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',


SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = 'correct'   
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'correct' 
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['email-address', 'formatted-name', 'public-profile-url', 'picture-url']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = [
    ('id', 'id'),
    ('formattedName', 'name'),
    ('emailAddress', 'email_address'),
    ('pictureUrl', 'picture_url'),
    ('publicProfileUrl', 'profile_url'),
]
```

frontend

```
<li class="linkedin"><a href="{% url  "social:begin" "linkedin-oauth2" %}">Login with LinkedIn</a></li>
```

urls.py

```
path('social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
```

Comment: Did you select following scope inside of Linkedin app permissions and also new handle is r_liteprofile

Comment: @iklinac no didn't select that because I can't find any of  those options on the developer platform. it appears I must apply  to the **Marketing Partner Program** before I can change any thing on the Linkedin app permissions

Answer (score 0):

the reason you are having trouble with r_basicprofile , is that Linked in only   gives the folowing scopes

> **r_emailaddress**   Use the primary email address associated with your LinkedIn account

> **r_liteprofile** Use your name and photo

> **w_member_social**  Create, modify, and delete posts, comments, and reactions on your behalf

so most likely  you are trying to follow a toutorial  that was written a long time ago before   linkedin  removed the r_basicprofile

please note that the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/  does mention 3 different scope permission (lite, basic, and Full) profiles ,  but  in reality linkedin developer app only grant  you the r_liteprofile

so to solve the problem   just change  the line

> SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']

to

> SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['r_liteprofile', 'r_emailaddress']

this  will solve  the scope  problem <  but  I am not sure  if  it  will retrive the profileUrl or the picture

Answer (score 0):

[image]

please check your product select sign in with linkedIn or not